# Nagios server status on confluence

Tags: nagios, confluence, nagiosxi

Is it possible to print/display Nagios server status report on confluence page? I want to automate it so confluence page grabs data and display on its side

Comment: Please anybody knew anything about it?

Comment: You can try put iframe from Nagios to Confluence page. See more details here - https://confluence.atlassian.com/confkb/how-to-put-an-iframe-into-confluence-598837531.html